# Wordpress' wp_get_nav_menu_items() doesn't return items on frontend?

Tags: wordpress, frontend

Basically, I'm getting 0 results when firing this function from frontend, as opposed to when I'm firing it from backend. Is it supposed to work this way? Can I override this somehow if it is?

EDIT: Apparently, if you want to call this function from the frontend (aka if !is_admin() is true), you need to define the $wp_rewrite variable like this

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite = new WP_Rewrite();
```

and after that you can call wp_get_nav_menu_items().

Comment: Do you have any code associated to this question that might be useful to use?

Comment: Nevermind, figured out what was wrong.